# Solving the second order, linear non-autonomous differential equation mystery.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following second order linear differential equation:

$$(x-1) \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = b^2 f-\left(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}\right) f,$$

where $a$, and $b$ are constants, and $f=f(x)$.

My attempt is based on a splitting of variables method, and I occasionally use the prime notation $f'= \frac{df}{dy}$:

$$ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} \frac{1}{f} = \frac{ b^2-(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x})}{x-1}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{f'}{f}\right)+\left(\frac{f'}{f}\right)^2 = \frac{ b^2-(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x})}{x-1}$$
$$d \left(\frac{f'}{f}\right) +  \frac{(df)^2}{dx} \frac{1}{f^2} = \frac{ b^2-(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x})}{x-1} dx$$
$$d \left(\frac{f'}{f}\right) dx +  \frac{(df)^2}{f^2}  = \frac{ b^2-(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x})}{x-1} dx dx$$
$$ \int \int d \left(\frac{f'}{f}\right) dx + \int \int \frac{df df}{f^2}  =  \int \int \frac{ b^2-(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x})}{x-1} dx dx$$

From the first to the second line, I have used:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{df}{dx} \frac{1}{f}\right) = \frac{f''}{f} - \left(\frac{f'}{f}\right)^2 \rightarrow \frac{f''}{f} = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{f'}{f}\right) +\left(\frac{f'}{f}\right)^2.$$

In the third and fourth line, I have multiplied both sides with $dx$.

The right hand side of this equation can be thrown into Mathematica and is not so problematic. I am more concerned about what happens on the left hand side. For the first integral notice that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \log(f) = \frac{1}{f} \frac{df}{dx} \rightarrow \int \frac{1}{f} \frac{df}{dx} dx = \log(f)$$

Thus we have

$$ \int \int d \left(\frac{f'}{f}\right) dx = \int \frac{f'}{f} dx = \log(f).$$

For the second integral we have

$$\int \int \frac{1}{f^2} df df = -\int \frac{1}{f} df = - \log(f).$$

Hence, the two integrals on the left hand side combined gives

$$ \log(f) - \log(f) = 0$$

which is a bit problamatic, since I want to solve for $f$. Hopefully, it's a stupid, little mistake somewhere, but I don't see where I am going wrong, or how else to solve it analytically (if possible).

If any one sees where it is going wrong, or has any tip or tools on how to solve this, it is very much appriciated.

Have a nice day!

2 minutes later...

The moment I finished typing this question, I noticed I ignored the integration constant:

$$ \int \int d \left(\frac{f'}{f}\right) dx = \int \frac{f'}{f} +c_1 dx = \log(f) + c_1 x + c_2,$$

and

$$\int \int \frac{1}{f^2} df df = -\int \frac{1}{f} +c_3 df = - \log(f) + c_3 f + c_4,$$

thus the solution might be

$$ c_3 f +c_1 x + c_5 =  \int \int \frac{ b^2-(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x})}{x-1} dx dx$$

which I think is quite remarkable, and a bit suspicious.
If I take the second derivative with respect to $x$ on both sides I get

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \left( c_3 f +c_1 x + c_5 \right)= \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \int \int \frac{ b^2-(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x})}{x-1} dx dx$$
$$  c_3 \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}=  \frac{ b^2-(\frac{2a^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x})}{x-1}$$
which is not the original equation. If anyone still see another mistake, I am happy to know.